# TypeError: o.element is undefined - jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using `jquery-ui`. I cannot solve this after 2 weeks.

I don't know why I got this error after clicking on sliders:

console Firefox:

```
TypeError: o.element is undefined[Learn More]  jquery-ui.min.js:6:6058
```

console chrome:

```
jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._toggleClass (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:6067)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._addClass (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:5877)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseCapture (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:14171)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseCapture (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:1111)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDown (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:9414)
    at t.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)._mouseDown (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:1111)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js:6:8701)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/persian-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: -10000000,
            max: -1000,
            values: [ -8000000, -2000 ],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $(".amount .min-price").text(addCommas (ui.values[1]*-1) + " ریال ");
                $(".amount .max-price").text(addCommas (ui.values[0]*-1) + " ریال ");
            }
        });

        $(".amount .min-price").text(addCommas ($("#slider").slider( "values", 1 )*-1  ) + " ریال ");
        $(".amount .max-price").text(addCommas ($("#slider").slider( "values", 0 )*-1  ) + " ریال ");
        // Hover states on the static widgets
        $( "#dialog-link, #icons li" ).hover(
            function() {
                $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-hover" );
            },
            function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-hover" );
            }
        );

    });

</script>
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="slider" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header">

        </div>
        <span tabindex="1" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default">

        </span>
        <span tabindex="2" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" >

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
//used in slider
function addCommas(nStr){
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

My site address:

http://tahrircenter.com/products

[image]

---

I removed extra codes but I got the same error:

[image]

It works fine on `jsfiddle` !!!:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3gm3sfem/

> .toggleClass() is a function of jQuery, so if you're getting an error
> that it's undefined, then it's possible another version of jQuery may
> be loaded elsewhere. Or it's not being loaded at all.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and solved it.

I accidentally set the slider to a value which was undefined.
At that point, no error was produced.

But, when I later tried to move the slider, I got the error o.element is undefined.

When I set the slider to a good value, the problem disappeared.

Comment: which value was undefined?

Comment: This appears to be a problem when any of the slider parameters (:ie: `min`, `max`, `value`, etc) that expect integer numbers are given anything else... like nulls or strings.